# A random noise function in Python

Tags: python, random

I'm writing a game in Python in which the environment is generated randomly. Currently, the game's "save" function works by writing out all parts of the environment which the player has explored. The result is that save files are larger than they need to be—why write random data to disk when you can just generate it again?

What I could use is a random noise function: a function `noise` such that `noise(x)` returns a random number, and always the *same* number whenever it's called with the same value of `x`. Now, for each point `(x,y)` in the game's environment, instead of generating a random number using `random()` and storing the result in `env[(x,y)]`, I can generate a random number using `noise((x,y))`, throw it away, and generate the same number later.

Comment: Another option would be to use `hashlib`, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: A lookup-friendly architecture would be a hash map of some sort.

Comment: In what sense is `hashlib` overkill? If `hashlib.md5` is X times slower than `random.random`, you can find a faster hash algorithm that's good enough. If your concern were that even `md5` isn't good enough (doesn't guarantee the same random period as `MersenneTwister`) that would be a different story, but overkill, you can overcome.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure if I'm stating the obvious, but using some variation of a Perlin noise generator is a common way to do this. [This post](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=15777) is a nice description of doing exactly this (as mentioned in the comments, it's [not exactly Perlin noise](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=15777&cpage=1#comment-277055))

For a given position, the Perlin function will return a random value (the position can be 2D, 3D or any dimensionality).

There is a [noise](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/) module, and [this page](http://www.fundza.com/c4serious/noise/perlin/) has a implementation of it

There's a similar thread on [gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/how-to-create-reproducible-probability-in-map-generation)

Comment: +1, this is the canonical way to do this in games.  In addition, it has a distinct advantage over seeded random numbers or typical hash functions in that although the output is noisey, it is continuous! Continuity makes it superior for this sort of application.  (The continuity requirement was a key motivation for inventing Perlin noise in the first place)

Comment: "this page" link is dead

Comment: @Sterling Fixed, page seemed to be renamed from `.../perlin/perlin.html` to http://www.fundza.com/c4serious/noise/perlin/

Answer (score 2):

First, if you need it to be true that noise(x) would always return the same value for the same x, no matter what, even if it's never been called, then you can't really use randomness at all. A good hash function is the only possibility.

However, if you just need to be able to restore a previous state consisting of the values for all of the *previously-explored* points (never-explored points may turn out different after save and load than if you hadn't quit… but how can anyone tell without access to multiple universes?), and you don't want to store all of those points, then it might be reasonable to regenerate them.

But let's back up a step. You want something that acts like a hash function. Is there a hash function you can use?

I'd imagine the algorithms in `hashlib` are too slow (`md5` is probably the fastest, but test them all), but I wouldn't reject them without actually testing.

It's possible that the "random period" of `zlib.adler32` (or `zlib.crc32`) is too short, but I wouldn't reject it (except maybe `hash`) without thinking through whether it's good enough. For that matter, even `hash` plus a decent fixed-side blender function might be good enough (at least on a 64-bit system).

Python doesn't come with anything "between" `md5` and `adler32' out of the box. But you can find PyPI modules or source recipes for hundreds of other hash algorithms. For that matter, if you're familiar with any particular hash algorithm that sounds good, most of them are trivial—you could probably code up, e.g., an [FNV hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) with xor-folding in less time than it takes you to look through the alternatives.

Also, keep in mind that you can generate a bunch of random bytes at "new game" time, store that in the save file, and use it as salt to your hash function.

If you've exhausted the possibilities are you really *do* need more randomness than a fast-enough hash function with arbitrary salt can give you alone, then:

It sounds like you'll already need to store a list of the points the user has explored (because how else do you know which points you need to restore?). And the order doesn't really matter. So, you can store them in the order of exploration. That means you can regenerate the values deterministically (just by iterating the list). Which means you can use the suggestion by @delnan on your own answer.

However, `seed` is not the way to do that. It isn't guaranteed to put the RNG into the same state each time across runs, Python versions, machines, etc. For that, you need `setstate`:

- To save, call `random.getstate()`, and pickle and stash the result.
- To load, read and unpickle the state, and call `random.setstate(state)`.

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.getstate) for full details.

If you're using a `random.Random` instance, it's exactly the same, except of course that you have to construct a `random.Random` before you can call `setstate` on it.

This is guaranteed to work between runs of your program, across machines, etc. Even with a newer version of Python. However, it's *not* guaranteed to work with an *older* version of Python. (That is, if the user saves a game with Python 2.6, then tries to load it with 2.5, the state will not be compatible. I believe the only problems come with 2.6->older and 2.3->older, but of course there's no guarantee there won't be additional ones in the future.) I'd suggest stashing the Python version, and if they've downgraded, show a warning saying "This save file requires Python 2.6 or later. You have Python 2.5. The load may fail. Continue anyway?"

This is only guaranteed for `random.Random` and for the `random` module itself (since the top-level module functions just use a hidden `random.Random`). In particular, `random.SystemRandom` are explicitly documented not to work.

Practically speaking, you can also just pickle a `random.Random` directly, because the state gets pickled in. It seems like that ought to work, or what would be the sense of pickling a `Random` object? And it definitely does work. But it isn't actually documented to work, so I'd stick with pickling the `getstate`, for safety.

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation of `noise` is this:

```
import random

def noise(point):
    gen = random.Random()
    gen.seed(point)
    return gen.random()
```

I don't know how fast `Random.seed()` is, though. In addition, `Random` may change from one version of Python to the next, causing the players of my game to find that the environment changes when they upgrade.

Comment: But the map changing if they upgrade seems like a very quirky feature of your game xD

Comment: Seeding the PRNG is awfully slow compared to generating the next output. `timeit` on Python 3.3 puts seed() at 38µs/call and random() at 0.36µs/call (read: 100x slower). If one wants a determinic stream of random numbers, seed it once with a deterministic value, then make sure to use the outputs in a deterministic order.

Comment: @delnan That would work in theory, but the player isn't going to explore the environment in a deterministic order. Something I could do, though, is to seed the PRNG once per (say) 32x32 area, generate all 1024 random numbers in a single go, and cache the result.

Comment: `Random.seed` is not guaranteed to put the RNG into the same state each time—although it _probably_ will, it's not documented to, so they could break that at any time. Also, this forces a redesign of the app logic, to see the RNG with some known value whenever the value is known, which is unnecessary.